# Bcrypt in node.js http request error 500

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I want to make create users with hash password, and when i am sending http request i have code error 500 Internal Server Error. Can someone tell me what is wrong??

```
router.post('/create', function (req, res, next) {

  var newUser = {
    login: req.body.login,
    password: req.body.password,
  }

  bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, function (err, hash) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      newUser.password = hash;
      var user = new User(newUser);
      user.save()
        .then(function (User) {
          res.send(User);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: A 500 error would result in errors being logged, but for starters, `password` is undefined.

Comment: thanks i forget about set name of obiekt before password